# AngularJS dynamic template update

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an AngularJS app that I do not have access to update, however I do have the ability to execute JavaScript after page load/init.

What I need to do is update a bunch of text in the component markup. But I can't update the stuff within the AngularJS repeater element (related-items) because it looks like Angular has already compiled it as a template when the page initialised.

Where can I hack into the scope to get access to the repeater template to update the markup and re-compile it?

```
<div class="item-grid" ng-controller="ItemGridCtrl" ng-cloak item-grid>

    <h2>Item Grid</h2>

    <div class="item-grid__item-details">
        <div class="item-grid__item0">

            <button add-item="{12345}">ADD</button>

        </div>            
        <div class="item-grid__item1"> ... </div>
        <div class="item-grid__item2"> ... </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item-grid__modal" item-grid-modal>
        <h3>Want to add another item?</h3>
        <div related-items ng-repeat="item in relatedItems">
            <div class="item-grid__related-item" data-related-item-info>
                <span class="item-grid__heading">{{item.title}}</span>
                <span class="item-grid__label">TEXT TO CHANGE</span>
                <button class="item-grid__btn" related-item="{{item.id}}">ADD+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


(function (modules) {

    //register this module to be injected into the main app as a dependency.
    modules.push("FooApp.itemGrid");

    //define "Product Grid" module
    var app = angular.module("FooApp.itemGrid", []);

    app.controller('ItemGridCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope',
    function ($scope, $rootScope) {

        //does controller stuff

    }]);

    app.directive('addItem', ['FooService', '$rootScope', '$timeout',
    function(FooService, $rootScope, $timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: false,
            link: function($scope, el, attrs) {

                el.bind('click', function(e) {

                    //http post to add item to session
                    FooService.addItem({$scope.getJsonData(), function(response){

                        //post successful... pop up modal to show related items

                        $scope.relatedItems = $scope.filterSomeData();

                        if ($scope.relatedItems.length > 0) {
                            $scope.modal.show(); //popup the modal
                            $scope.modal.find('[ng-repeat] [data-related-item-info]').each(function() {
                                window.foo.angular.components.attachComponents(this);
                            });
                        }

                    });
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }]);


    app.directive('itemGridModal', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: false,
            link: function($scope, el, attrs) {
                $scope.modal = el.find('[modal]'); //adds modal element to controller scope
            }
        };
    }]);

})(window.foo.angularModules);
```

Comment: I think this [dynamicTemplate service](https://github.com/BurakAkyildiz/angularJs-dynamic-conditional-templates) helpfull for this case.

Answer (score 1):

To change the template, you'll probably need to get access to the $templateCache service for that angular app. Not any kind of $scope.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache

Not sure if it's possible to do that, but good luck if you can, because that would be cool.

---

An alternate solution would be to use a MutationObserver (native browser class) to listen for DOM changes and run your own code to check/update the view after angular has done its part. This would be a heavier solution to modifying the $templateCache, but it can definitely work.

```
var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(_.debounce(handleDomChanges, 25));
mutationObserver.observe(element, {childList: true, subtree: true, attributes: false});
```

Note: The _.debounce function is a lo-dash library method that prevents this callback from getting run too many times each second.

Comment: Yes I mention $scope because I'm already jumping into that to update the data used by the repeater. I guess the question should be, "where should I look?". Agree MutationObserver seems a lot of work for little gain in my particular situation. But thanks for the $templateCache hint, I'll follow that up and see what I can see.